# Converting an argument to [lower case] in `expl3` context

Tags: expl3, tocloft

I often call the the macro `\newlistof{<entry>}{<ext>}{<list of names>}` with `<entry>` and `<ext>` identical except in their capitalization. So, I'm trying to automate this convention, but my two attempts failed:

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \__erw_newlistof_i:nnn
{%
  \newlistof{#1}{#2}{#3}
}
\cs_new:Nn \__erw_newlistof_ii:nnn
{%
  \newlistof{#2}{#1}{#3}
}

%\__erw_newlistof:nnn{Foo}{foo}{Title} % OK

%\exp_last_unbraced:Nx \__erw_newlistof_i:nnn
%{%
%  {Foo}%
%  {\MakeLowercase{Foo}}%
%  {Title}%
%}%ERROR: Argument of \@fileswith@pti@ns has an extra }.

%\exp_args:Nf \__erw_newlistof_ii:nnn
%  {\MakeLowercase{Foo}}%
%  {Foo}%
%  {Title}% ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted.

\ExplSyntaxOff

%\newlistof{Foo}{\MakeLowercase{Foo}}{Title}% ERROR: Missing \endcsname inserted.
\newlistof{Foo}
{foo}
{Title} % OK

\begin{document}

\listofFoo

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `\__erw_newlistof:nnn { \str_lower_case:n {Foo} } {foo} {Title}`?

Comment: BTW: small caps and lower case are not the same thing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure about the usefulness of writing code for dealing with a handful of cases.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft} % for newlistof
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \erw_newlistof:nnn
 {
  \newlistof{#1}{#2}{#3}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \erw_newlistof:nnn { ne }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \erw_newlistof:nnnn
 {
  \newlistof[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \erw_newlistof:nnnn { nne }


\NewDocumentCommand{\NewListOf}{omO{#2}m}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \erw_newlistof:nen { #2 } { \str_lowercase:n { #3 } } { #4 }
   }
   {
    \erw_newlistof:nnen { #1 } { #2 } { \str_lowercase:n { #3 } } { #4 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewListOf{Foo}{Title foo}
\newcommand{\Foo}[1]{\addcontentsline{foo}{section}{#1}\par}
\NewListOf[section]{Baz}[zab]{Title baz}
\newcommand{\Baz}[1]{\addcontentsline{zab}{section}{#1}\par}

\begin{document}

\listofFoo
\listofBaz

\Foo{x}

\Baz{y}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "not really sure about the usefulness of writing code for dealing with a handful of cases." `~/Documents $ find write/letters -type f -name '*tex' | wc -l
400` and counting.

Comment: @Erwann How many times do you use `\newfloat` in a *single* document?

Comment: I automate all repetitive tasks related to `tocloft`. What I learn in one area has spillovers in others. Usage is the ultimate judge. TU for pointing out this  application of `generate_variant`, it had eluded me. I was about the reinvent the wheel.